# Multiple autosuggestion in an input based on Category and criteria

Tags: jquery

I need some inputs on the multiple autosuggestion while searching.
The search string consists of Category, optional Criteria and value.

Example : Category.Criteria

I tried using jquery with the autocomplete, the first level for category of autosuggest works fine, once the user selects a Category and types in “.” 
We are supposed to show the Criteria’s configured for that Category.

The 2nd set of auto suggestion does not appear immediately when the user select a category and types a ".", but it appears once we focus out of the input area and come back.

Hers is the code https://jsfiddle.net/krishnanpb/gh32nad6/1/

Steps:
1. select a category and then type ".", move out of the input area and refocus the second set of suggestion appears.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        BindControls();
    });

    function BindControls() {
        var Categories = [
        "Customer",
        "Equipment",
        "Link",
        "Location",
        "Network",
        "Service",
        "Termination"];

        $('#tags').autocomplete({
            source: Categories,
            minLength: 0,
            scroll: true
        }).focus(function() {
            $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
        });

        $('#tags').bind('keypress', function(e) {

            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if(code == 46) { 
            console.log(". pressed");
            var Criteria = [
            "name",
            "id"];
            }
            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                source: Criteria
            });
        });
    }
```

html :

Tags:

Answer (score 0):

You should use the KeyUp event. I also forced it to re-focus on the input after changing the source.

```
$( "#tags" ).keyup(function( event ) {
    if(event.which == 190) { 
        console.log(". pressed");
        var Criteria = ["name", "id"];
        $('#tags').autocomplete({ source: Criteria });
        $('#tags').focus();
    }
});
```